# Symfony 2 : Doctrine : Pagination with Joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I would like to paginate a complex request with at least 2 left joins, but the pagination bundle I'm using (KnpPaginationBundle) can't tell Doctrine how to count the result (which is needed for the pagination process), and keep having this Exception.
    Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction
    500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $user->getId();

    $dql   = "SELECT o FROM DefaultBundle:Offer o ,DefaultBundle:FavoriteOffer fo WHERE fo.offerid=o.id and fo.userid =".$user->getId();

    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $table  = $paginator->paginate($query, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 10);
```

Any idea on how to paginate over a complex request thanks.

Favorite offer

```
class FavoriteOffer
{
/**
 * @var \Offer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Offer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Offerid", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $offerid;

/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Userid", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $userid;
```

Comment: Can you please add the entity code? So that i can get more idea about how your relations are mapped to each other.

Comment: Offer  1 -----  * FavoriteOffer
Every user can choose specific offer(Entity:Offer) and put them in a favorite list (FavoriteOffer)